NFS mount Ubuntu 22.04 - Connection timed out
I have two systems running on Ubuntu 22.04. I want to mount one of the disks of the server (PC1 - auerbach) on the client (PC2 - hubel) using NFS.
The /etc/exports file on PC1 looks like the following:
/media/auerbach-data    139.124.148.0/25(rw,no_subtree_check,sync,fsid=001)

I ran sudo exportfs -av on PC1 which works.
The /etc/fstab file on PC2 looks like the following:
auerbach:/media/auerbach-data      /mnt/auerbach-data    nfs     defaults,auto,rw        0       0

However, when I run sudo mount /mnt/auerbach-data -v on PC2, I get the error message:
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Nov 28 10:44:02 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=139.124.148.27,clientaddr=139.124.148.5'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out

What is really weird is that when I run showmount -e on PC1, I get:
Export list for PC1:
/media/auerbach-data 139.124.148.0/25

So it seems like the exportation itself works.
And when I then run showmount, I get:
Hosts on PC1:
PC2’s ip

Which seems to indicate PC1 sees PC2. Furthermore, when I run showmount -e auerbach on PC2, I get:
Export list for auerbach: 
/media/auerbach-data 139.124.148.0/25

After a bit of research to fix the issue, I used tcpdump -i eno145 host auerbach and figured that when running the mount command on PC2, PC1 didn't receive any information over the network. This isn't the case when I ping PC1 or use showmount. Some of the logs are listed below:
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eno145, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
10:52:29.203855 IP hubel.836 > auerbach.nfs: Flags [S], seq 3035191773, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3
448551700 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:52:30.244579 IP hubel.836 > auerbach.nfs: Flags [S], seq 3035191773, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3
448552741 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

Does anybody know how I could solve this issue? Thank you in advance!
Additional Information:
There is no Firewall on auerbach and port 2049 is open (checked with telnet).
When I use sudo mount -t nfs  auerbach:/media/auerbach-data /mnt/auerbach-data -v, I get:
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Nov 28 16:53:57 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=139.124.148.27,clientaddr=139.124.148.79'


I solved the issue. After some digging, I found this post: https://www.suse.com/fr-fr/support/kb/doc/?id=000019722. The root cause seems to be smart switch that detect and block TCP connection reuse. Since NFS relies on connection reuse, this was blocking any mount attempts. Removing the switch solved everything.
Does anyone know how to configure a switch so that it doesn’t filter connection reuse?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thank you for providing an answer! Could you please [edit] your answer to also include the specific steps from the link you posted that helped you solve the issue? Just a link, which could stop working any time, with some generic information isn't so much helpful for other users with similar issues. Additionally, if you have another question, please do ask one by clicking the Ask Question button on the top right of the page instead of including a question in the answer. Thanks!
